# Parse a Google Visualization Multi-Line Chart Data String for one data series

Tags: google-visualization

Setting up a page for my customers to view GA performance for their data.  In order to facilitate faster performance, using a CRONJOB to pull the GA data for all premium members "after hours" and stick it in a DB, so when they go to look at their data, they don't have to wait for the GA code to crunch.

Already have GA Charts working for a multi-line chart for a given members data but that is at the superset level.  IOW, the "google.visualization.arrayToDataTable()" string is being persisted in the DB with ALL their records.  This is fine, as one of the charts is a superset chart.  HOWEVER, need to also provide a line chart view for each item individually.  Since the superset data is already there, WHY go back and requery GA, just parse the existing data string for the record needed.

Before I go off an develop my own custom parser for that one record, wanted to ask if anyone is aware of something already existing?

Maybe create a JSON object from the string, identify the element needed, then print that back out in the string format?  Have done a little reading on that, but wanted to ask some 800lb brains before I spend alot of time going down that rabbit hole.

String data for the google.visualization.arrayToDataTable() function is in this format:

```
[{type: 'date', label: 'Date'},
{type: 'number', label: 'XYZ46570'},
{type: 'number', label: 'XYZ35512'},
{type: 'number', label: 'XYZ39964'}],
[new Date(2018,04,21),7,0,0],
[new Date(2018,04,22),4,1,0],
[new Date(2018,04,23),4,3,0],
[new Date(2018,04,24),4,1,0],
[new Date(2018,04,25),1,0,0]
```

This example is 4col, 5row string.  Therefore, what is needed is to parse the string for just one of the 'XYZ' labels such as 'XYZ35512'.  The resulting string would be used to create a single line GA chart:

```
[{type: 'date', label: 'Date'},
{type: 'number', label: 'XYZ35512'}],
[new Date(2018,04,21),0],
[new Date(2018,04,22),1],
[new Date(2018,04,23),3],
[new Date(2018,04,24),1],
[new Date(2018,04,25),0]
```

Thanks in advance for any help!
LarryG

Comment: create the full data table from the string, then use a [DataView](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#dataview-class) to filter the row(s) and column(s) -- the data view class has methods for `setRows` and `setColumns`...

Comment: @WhiteHat ... Sorry delay in responding ... LIFE popped up!  THANK YOU, that is exactly what I was looking for.  Had already used the DataTable but did not realize the DataView was available.  That will do nicely ... always nice when there is an EZ button!

Comment: cheers! let me know if you have any trouble, always glad to help...